# Finding how many instances there are of a certain prototype, in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance

How can I find how many instances there are for a certain prototype? For example, I define a prototype like so in javascript:

```
var foo = function(config) {
    this.x = config.x;
    ...
}
foo.prototype.update = function() {
    ...
}

var f = new foo(...);
var c = new foo(...);
...
```

How can I make it so there's a function that returns 2, because there are 2 instances of foo: f and c?

Comment: That's usually a bad idea, as your count doesn't know about garbage collection. Use an extra helper function for creating instances that updates the count accordingly.

Comment: this question technically has nothing to do with Processing.js (and I say that as the dev for Processing.js =). It's a plain JavaScript question, about JavaScript instance counting.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Oh, okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take full advantage of object-oriented programming.

**See this example [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3TPPh4mr1IhH11IT6It?p=preview)**

You can create a parent class to `foo` like so:

```js
function Bar() {
  this.foobars = [];
  console.log('new Bar',this.foobars);
}

Bar.prototype.add = function(foo) {
  console.log("Pushing");
  this.foobars.push(foo);
  console.log(this.foobars);
}

Bar.prototype.size = function(foo) {
  return this.foobars.length;
}

function Foo(config) {
  this.x = config.x;
  this.add(this);
  console.log('new Foo', Foo.prototype.foobars);
}

Foo.prototype = new Bar();

var f = new Foo({x:1});

var c = new Foo({x:2});

console.log("f.x:",f.x,"c.x:",c.x,"Foos: ",f.size());
```

and each instance of Foo will have access to the entire array of Foos in Bar. You can also just simply use a count instead of an array if you'd like.

When this code runs, here is the console output:

```
new Bar []
Pushing
[Foo]
new Foo [Foo]
Pushing
[Foo, Foo]
new Foo [Foo, Foo]
```

And the final console output will be:

> `f.x: 1 c.x: 2 Foos:  2`

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you. Let me know if you have any other questions about this!

Comment: please don't use `document.write` in an example, it's a rather dangerous and "doesn't do what you think at all" function, still around purely for historical reasons. `console.log` for just seeing "something", or creating a DOM node and then appendChild'ing it for on-page data prevents people from "learning" to use document.write

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I just did that as a quick way to show what was going on, but I changed it to console.log.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing plain javascript, instead of actual Processing code, just make use of the prototype concept in JavaScript:

```
// objects conventionally use CamelCase
var Foo = function(config) {
  this.instantiated();
  ...
};

var fooPrototype = {
  instances: 0,
  instantiated: function() {
    FooPrototype.instances++;
  },
  update: function() {
    ...
  },
  ...
};

Foo.prototype = fooPrototype;

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.instances); // -> "1"

var c = new Foo();
console.log(c.instances); // -> "2"
```

Because objects never create a local `instance` variable, shadowing the prototype value, every modification modifies the prototype variable, of which there is only one.

If, on the other hand, you're using real Processing, you'd just create a static class variable and increment that during constructor calls.

```
class Thing {
  static int instances = 0;
  Thing() {
    Thing.instances++;
  }
  int getInstanceCount() {
    return Thing.instances;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
var counter = 0;
for (prop in foo.prototype) {
   console.dir(prop);
   counter++;
}
console.log('total prototypes in foo: '+counter);
```

**UPDATE** 
I think you want to search for instances of foo?

f instanceof foo

Assuming

```
var foo = function(config) {
    this.x = config.x;
}
var config = new Object();
config.x = "1";
var f = new foo(config);
```

then

```
f instanceof foo
true
```

So then if you want to find all instances of foo in the global scope...

```
var counter = 0; //set the counter to zero
for (name in window) { //for property in global scope iteration
 if (window[name] instanceof foo) { // if property is an instance of foo then count it
   counter++;
 }
}
console.log('total instances of foo '+counter); //total count
```

I just tried this and swapped foo out for Object and made some new object that added to the count. I had to revise it a little. Hopefully this now makes sense.

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to determine how many prototypes there are of a function, rather how many instances there are. So how many of "var someName = new foo();" there are.

Comment: I tried it and it just returns what config.x equals. That's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: So the problem I had was using the wrong object for the global scope. I think you want window. I can verify from my screenshot that each new instance is getting counted when I run the for loop.

Comment: Although this works, it is not a good way of doing what you're trying to accomplish. Why would you search in a backwards way and loop through the entire window when you can just keep track of every instance? Check out my answer to see how to do it in an object-oriented way that doesn't use a for loop.